# How much is input delay from keyboard

Tags: keyboard, delay, timedelay

Assuming that OS running on host PC is real-time (has no extra delays when handling the input from keyboard) - how much is the value of delay between the moment when the single key is pressed on a keyboard and the moment when the keyboard controller generates an interrupt.

I understand that it vary depending on keyboard connection (ps/2, usb, laptop keyboard) and wire length (not taking into account wireless models). Maybe there are some common calculation already done?

Comment: Why?  Is this a programming question?

Comment: yes, I want to know how long (in ms) will this operation take and so does it make sense for me to use some custom external panel with button. I want to know what hardware in a keyboard usually causes the delay.

To be more exact - in my application i need to handle the moment when external button is pressed by user - with high level of accuracy. So I'm choosing between custom peripheral and standard keyboard.